# Scala bitfields serialization

Tags: scala, binary-serialization

I am extremely new at Scala and I'm getting confused by the bit manipulation features. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

I have a byte array defined with the following bit fields:

```
0-3 - magic number
  4 - version
5-7 - payload length in bytes
8-X - payload, of variable length, as indicated in bits 5-7
```

I would like to serialize this back and forth to a structure such as:

```
MagicNumber: Integer
Version: Integer
Length: Integer
payload: Array[Byte]
```

How do you deal with bits in this situation optimally? Most of the examples I've seen deal with higher level serialization, such as JSON. I am trying to serialize and deserialize TCP binary data in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Scala Pickling](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~hmiller/pickling/) or POF or Google Protobuf, but if your format is so restricted, the simplest way is to write your own serializer:

```
case class Data(magicNumber: Int, version: Int, payload: Array[Byte])

def serialize(data: Stream[Data]): Stream[Byte] = 
   data.flatMap(x => 
     Array((x.magicNumber << 4 | x.version << 3 | x.payload.length).toByte) ++ x.payload)

@scala.annotation.tailrec
def deserialize(binary: Stream[Byte], acc: Stream[Data] = Stream[Data]()): Stream[Data] =   
   if(binary.nonEmpty) {
     val magicNumber = binary.head >> 4 
     val version = (binary.head & 0x08) >>3 
     val size = binary.head & 0x07
     val data = Data(magicNumber, version, ByteVector(binary.tail.take(size).toArray)) 
     deserialize(binary.drop(size + 1), acc ++ Stream(data)) 
   } else acc
```

Or you can use [Scodec](https://github.com/scodec/scodec) library (this option is better because you will have automatical value range check):

Sbt:

```
  libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "scodec-core" % "1.3.0"
```

Codec:

```
  case class Data(magicNumber: Int, version: Int, payload: ByteVector)
  val codec = (uint(4) :: uint(1) :: variableSizeBytes(uint(3), bytes)).as[Data]
```

Use:

```
  val encoded = codec.encode(Data(2, 1, bin"01010101".bytes)).fold(sys.error, _.toByteArray)
  val decoded = codec.decode(BitVector(encoded)).fold(sys.error, _._2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I am also trying to look at scala pickling, but it's lacking examples unfortunately. i don't yet understand how I would do it with pickling/unpickling. For now, this is sufficient for me!

Comment: scodec is more bit-oriented than pickling, i have updated the answer with  working example for it. But it depends on heavy libraries like scalaz, shapeless.

Comment: Am I doing this right? I don't seem to be able to do a round trip: val input2 = new Data(0,3,Array[Byte]('h','e','l','l','o'))
val output2 = serialize(Stream(input2))
val output3 =  deserialize(output2)

Comment: That's why i recommend to use scodec (it has automatical range check). In your case version = 3. Maximum possible value for version (1 bit) is 1. You can also add assert (for magic < 2^4, version < 2, data.size < 2^3) to serialize function to avoid such non-roundtrip situation.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using bitfield manipulation simply because I didn't want to pull in additional big dependencies. It wasn't that hard but it could've been much easier if there was support for unsigned byte.

Answer (score 4):

I'd look at [scodec](http://typelevel.org/projects/scodec/). Based on the [UDP example](https://github.com/scodec/scodec/blob/master/shared/src/test/scala/scodec/examples/UdpDatagramExample.scala), it should be something like (untested):

```
import scodec.bits.{ BitVector, ByteVector }
import scodec.codecs._

case class Datagram(
  magicNumber: Int,
  version: Byte,
  payload: ByteVector)

object Datagram {
  implicit val codec: Codec[Datagram] = {
    ("magic_number" | int32 ) ::
    ("version" | byte ) ::
    variableSizeBytes(int(3),
      ("payload" | bytes ))
  }.as[Datagram]
}
```